# Loadable Components SSR - chunkNames in Server Stats file different from Client stats file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering, code-splitting, loadable-component

I am trying to set up loadable-components for an SSR un-ejected CRA app. I'm using Craco to override Webpack config and it seems to be working, as the client side `loadable-stats.json` is being generated. When I run the build command, the chunks are named based on id, as I believe `react-scripts` is hard-wired to run in production mode. So for my server config, I decided to name the chunks by id too. But unfortunately the chunkNames seem to be the path to the modules in the **server stats file**, which is generated by the `@loadable/webpack-plugin`, rather than id. The actual chunks are named by 'id` though, I can see them in the folder.

Here is my code in `server.js` where I'm trying to read the chunks.

```
const nodeStatsFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node-stats.json');
const nodeExtractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: nodeStatsFile, entrypoints: ["server"] });
const nodeEntryPointResult = nodeExtractor.requireEntrypoint("server");  // ==> {}
const webStatsFile = path.resolve(__dirname, '../web-stats.json');
const extractor = new ChunkExtractor({ statsFile: webStatsFile });
const client = generateApolloClient();
const app = (<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <HelmetProvider context={helmetContext}>
      <Router location={req.url} context={staticContext}>
        <CookiesProvider cookies={req.universalCookies}>
            <App />
        </CookiesProvider>
      </Router>
    </HelmetProvider>
  </ApolloProvider>);
getDataFromTree(app).then(() => {
  const jsx = nodeExtractor.collectChunks(app);
  const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(jsx);
  const state = client.extract();
  const { helmet } = helmetContext;

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Html content={content} helmet={helmet} assets={assets} extractor={extractor} />,
  );
  res.status(staticContext.status || 200);
  res.send(`<!doctype html>${html}`);
  res.end();
})
```

Due to this, when I run the `nodeExtractor` (which is reading from the server stats file) to collectChunks and then `webExtractor` (which is using the client stats file) to `getScriptElements` I get an empty array of loadable chunks. If I only use the `webExtractor` it throws an error that `chunkNameFromServerStatsFile not found`.

My webpack config for the server is using the `server.js` file, which contains the Express code, as the entry point, whereas the Webpack config for the client has the index file for the app as the entry. I get an empty {} as the server `requireEntrypoint` result. I'm not really sure what is supposed to happen with that call, the actual documentation is not very clear.

Some people are using the `webExtractor` only in the server code as well and it seems to be working for them, but I keep getting an error as it's still trying to map the server-side chunks, which it cannot find in the `webExtractor`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So this was happening because I forgot to include the `@loadable/babel-plugin` into my Craco config, for the client-side Webpack build. Works fine after I did that. My final `craco.config.js` is:

```
const LoadablePlugin = require('@loadable/webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
 babel: {
   plugins: ["@loadable/babel-plugin"]  
 },
webpack: {
 mode: "development",
 configure: {
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].js',
  },
 },
 plugins: [
  new LoadablePlugin(),
 ]
} };
```

Works perfectly now.