# Server side rendering and codesplitting using create react app and loadable components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, server-side-rendering, loadable-component

Anyone have any experience converting a react app created with `create-react-app` to using server side rendering and code splitting via [`loadable-components`](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components)? I know this is a general question, but mostly looking for general guidance or any major red flags for this approach.  I'd like to keep the nice things you get out of box with `create-react-app` - especially the live reload dev environment - while adding in optimizations using SSR and code splitting.  I was able to mostly get this working using `express` backend and `handlebars` templating, but I'm facing many challenges getting code splitting working correctly with this setup.  Any hints / stories are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) "an easy and comprehensible configuration layer for create-react-app".

Webpack custom configurations go into `craco.config.js`, inside root folder.

SSR is possible, you can check two related questions that might help you with your case:
[Code splitting loads all chunk files on chrome but load them separately in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950103/code-splitting-loads-all-chunk-files-on-chrome-but-load-them-separately-in-firef)
[Loadable Components SSR - chunkNames in Server Stats file different from Client stats file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235886/loadable-components-ssr-chunknames-in-server-stats-file-different-from-client)